# virtualenvwrapper installation error

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I've installed `pip` and `virtualenvwrapper` through `pip`. I added the following lines to my `.bashrc`

```
# virutalenvwrapper                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I'm getting an error once I source `.bash_profile`:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenv has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

What is this error? I've seen a lot of people with the same error and I've tried the suggestions listed and none seem to work with me.

I am running OS X Mountain Lion and Python 2.7.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` the actual path of virtualenv?

Comment: Yes. `$ which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `which virtualenv` to see virtualenv's path

Comment: `$ which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`.  So it's correct isn't it?

Comment: yes it is. Are you using a shell compatible with `virtualenvwrapper`? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Yes I do. I just fixed it though. My whole installation of `virtualenv` was messed up. I uninstalled everything and reinstalled and it worked. Thanks!